# Azure Usage Scaled Rates Pricing

Tags: azure, scale, billing, rate

I try to calculate the price for a meterID that has scaled rates . I use this 
as guide for the algorithm ( public static double computeRatedUsagePerMeter(Dictionary rates, double usage) ) 
https://github.com/PartnerCenterSamples/Commerce-API-DotNet/blob/master/Usage.cs

Comparing with the price from azure pricing calculator if i ask the price for quantity X in calculator it is equal  to the price that i calculate from the above method  but for quantity X - 1.

So i am confused if the method provided from Microsoft is complete or not , or maybe just a hint for the right direction.

---

```
 private static decimal computeRatedUsagePerMeter(Dictionary<decimal, decimal> rates, decimal usage)
        {
            decimal total = Decimal.Zero;

            if (rates.Count == 0)
                return Decimal.Zero;
            else if (rates.Count == 1)
                return (usage * rates.Values.FirstOrDefault());

            var remainingUsage = usage;

            while (rates.Count > 0)
            {
                decimal LastKey = rates.Keys.Last();

                if (remainingUsage > LastKey)
                {
                    decimal LastKeyValue = Decimal.Zero;
                    if (rates.TryGetValue(LastKey, out LastKeyValue))
                    {
                        total = total + ((remainingUsage - LastKey + 1) * LastKeyValue); // remainingUsage - LastKey +1  because tiered pricing is exclusive
                        remainingUsage = LastKey - 1;
                    }
                    rates.Remove(LastKey);
                }
                else if (remainingUsage <= LastKey)
                {
                    rates.Remove(LastKey);
                }
            }
            return total;
        }
```

---

```
{
      "MeterId": "d23a5753-ff85-4ddf-af28-8cc5cf2d3882",
      "MeterName": "Standard IO - Page Blob/Disk (GB)",
      "MeterCategory": "Storage",
      "MeterSubCategory": "Locally Redundant",
      "Unit": "GB",
      "MeterTags": [],
      "MeterRegion": "",
      "MeterRates": {
        "0": 0.042165,
        "1024": 0.0421650,
        "51200": 0.0421650,
        "512000": 0.0421650,
        "1024000": 0.0379485,
        "5120000": 0.0312021
      },
      "EffectiveDate": "2014-02-01T00:00:00Z",
      "IncludedQuantity": 0.0
    }
```

According to the method provided by the link above the price for quantity 1  = 0.084330   while azure pricing calculator  gives 0.04
( the prices are in EUR )

And another example : les say 100 quantity.

method: 4.258665 EUR

Azure Calculator = 4.22  EUR

method for 99 quantity = 4.216500  which rounded is 4.22 EUR. 
[image: azure calculator]
Also cannot check the prices < 1.00 lets say 0.5 quantity ( in this case its measured in GB so 0,5 GB is perfectly reasonable quantity ) cause pricing calculator doesn't allow decimal .

Comment: Can you include an example please?

Comment: What does a JSON snippet have to do with calculating something? Please post the code you use, the expected results and what was actually returned. Not a link to some *similar* code

Comment: it is an example and i will add the code also and as you can see the code is not similar but exactly the same .

Comment: The json is the rates as provided from MS Azure CREST API .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the method provided by the link above the price for
>   quantity 1 = 0.084330 while azure pricing calculator gives 0.04 ( the
>   prices are in EUR )

Looking at the code above, I believe there's an issue in the code itself. Essentially you're trying to find the price for 1 GB of storage which would fall under `0 - 1023` range or in other words the value of `LastKey` is `0`. So when the following code executes:

```
total = total + ((remainingUsage - LastKey + 1) * LastKeyValue);
```

it gives you a total of `0.084330` (`0 + (1 - 0 + 1) * 0.042165`).

> Also cannot check the prices < 1.00 lets say 0.5 quantity ( in this
>   case its measured in GB so 0,5 GB is perfectly reasonable quantity )
>   cause pricing calculator doesn't allow decimal.

I am sure someone from Microsoft would provide a proper answer as to why they designed the calculator the way it is designed.

Comment: I just want to make clear that the code is taken from Microsoft's azure github with the only difference that i changed double to decimal . Thank you for pointing out that indeed there is something wrong .

Comment: Even Microsoft is allowed to mistakes :)